# Deleting file from app's private storage

Tags: android, file-io, illegalargumentexception

I have a problem, when i try to delete a file from `/data/data/com.mycompany.appname/files/mydir/`.

I have the following code:

```
class MyClass extends android.content.ContextWrapper;
//...
private void delete() {
    String file = getFilesDir() + "/" + (getString(R.string.directory_logs) + "/" + selectedLogFile).substring(1);
    file = file.replaceAll("/", File.separator);
    //here the value of file is:"/data/data/com.mycompany.appname/files/mydir/my_file.log"
    if (FileOperation.delete(file)) {
        //Do something if deleting was successfull
    }
}
```

The `FileOperation.delete()` method is:

```
public static boolean delete(String fileOrDirectory) {
    return delete(new File(fileOrDirectory));
}

public static boolean delete(File fileOrDirectory) {
    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()) {
        for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles()) {
            delete(child);
        }
    }
    return fileOrDirectory.delete();
}
```

The answer of `FileOperation.delete()` will always be false.

I tried to call `ContextWrapper.deleteFile(file)` instead of my delete method, but it throws IllegalArgumentException with the message:

> File /data/data/com.mycompany.appname/files/mydir/my_file.log contains a path separator

Could you help me how to delete a file in a directory?

Comment: Are you sure is not /data/com.comp..... ? it is /data/data ?

Comment: `/data/data/package.name` is correct on all devices I know of. What does `File#exists()` say about the file?

Comment: exists() answer is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange error, but

- only root has permissions for delete this file
- when you reinstall app with changes, this file will be deleted or recreated

And if you have rooted phone, not all users have too.

Comment: I want ot delete a file from /data/data/com.mycompany.appname/files/ from my own app (com.mycompany.appname). Are you sure it needs root permission?

Comment: no, that's not true. You can do whatever you like with files in your app folder

Comment: Yeah sorry the file has permissions of your app, because this file was created with your app that running under your app account, but /data/data folder needs root permissions for making anything. So you can try previous solution [File.separator](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#separator)

Comment: I have this line:
file = file.replaceAll("/", File.separator);

Comment: have you tried [context.deleteFile()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteFile%28java.lang.String%29), how i understand just pass same name that you use for openFileInput method.

Comment: i have tried deleteFile("mydir/my_file.log");
it was not throws Exception. It simple answers false.

Comment: You have answered under your post that files doesn't exist, make sure that you have create file with File.exist(), when it gives you true try to delete file with context.deleteFile();

Comment: exists() give false. But i am sure it exists, because in first step i list files form mydir, then select one, then try to delete

Comment: It is true. there was no files. Trey were in the external storage. On save i used Context.getExternalFilesDir(null), and on delete i used Context.getFilesDir().
Thans for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
File x = new File(path_to_file);
if ( x.delete() ) ...
```

Also you do not need to replace "/" with file separator. It is ok to let it like "/"